# Delete element by parameter value in json tree

Tags: jquery, json, tree

I know that there are a lot of similar questions, but no one the same.
I have a quite complicated json tree:

```
"items": [
    {
    "slug": "level_1",
    "items": [
        { 
        "slug": "level_1_1"
        },
        {
        "slug": "level_1_2",
        "items": [
             {
             "slug": "level_1_2_1",
             },
             {
             "slug": "level_1_2_2"
             }
        ] 
        }
    ]},
    {
    "slug": "level_2"
    }
 ]
```

I need to have a function to delete/remove json element by "slug" value. Is it possible?
I try everything that I found without success. I can use javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process the tree recursively: you want a list consisting of the recursively-processed element, for each element that does **not** have a matching 'slug' value. The recursive processing consists of creating a new object, with the original slug and an 'items' list filtered by recursively calling the function.

Something like:

```
function my_filter(json_array, slug_to_remove) {
    return $.map(json_array, function(element) { 
        return (element.slug == slug_to_remove) ? null : {
            slug: element.slug, items: my_filter(element.items, slug_to_remove)
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello Karl! You dicover $.map for me! Thank you! In fact your solution have a mistake. If 'items' in child node will be null exception occurs. I update your solution:

function my_filter(json_array, slug_to_remove) {

    return $.map(json_array, function (element) {

        return (element.slug == slug_to_remove) ? null :  {

            slug: element.slug, items: (element.items == null) ? element.pages : 

            my_filter(element.items, slug_to_remove)

        };

    });

}

Comment: I didn't know there is an `element.pages` in your data, but I am happy you were able to make it work :)

Comment: oh sorry, I have use "pages" in real project instead of "items". It's a remark. =)